# Oracle Date comparison issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with dates, there is something very weird about it.

When i query the table

```
select distinct process_dt from table;
```

The output is : 11/16/2013

When i query the table

```
select process_dt from table 
where process_dt=to_date('20131116', 'YYYYMMDD');
```

The output is 0 records.

When i query the table

```
select process_dt from table 
where process_dt=trunc(process_dt);
```

the output give 100 rows, all say 11/16/2013.

I am not understanding why my second query is not working. Any idea? should i change the session in a certain way?

Comment: how is the column defined?

Comment: the column data type is Date.

Comment: is it possible that the typo in your second select statement causes it? You have typed `selct`

Comment: run `select to_char(process_dt,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') from table;` to see why.

Comment: Is the output actually showing `2013`, or is it perhaps just showing `13` and you're assuming the century? Then the table values might really be `1913` or `0013`, from a botched insert. That's the only thing I can think of that would give that kind of result for all three queries.

Comment: What you have not done here, it seems, is actually look at the data in the table. "select to_char(process_dt,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ..."

Comment: @user2040673 - you mentioned partitioning in a comment. If you really do have those dates present, without times, and they are your partition keys you might be hitting a bug - there are several where querying on the partition key index gives wrong results. There is too little information here to guess which it might be, or even do more than speculate that it is even a bug. *If* that is the case you could consider patching or upgrading; or raise a service request with Oracle. You should still demonstrate that you really do have a problem by showing the output Jeffrey and David asked for.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your current check is that the date data type also contains the time. You need to use trunc for the date column to make this work.

Comment: SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') from dual where trunc(SYSDATE) = trunc(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD')) - WOrks!!

Comment: Having a time set would explain query 2, but not query 1 (unless they all have the same time, which is feasible), or query 3 - which is already using `trunc`. If all the dates have a time, `process_date = trunc(process_date)` would always be false and you'd get no rows back. If any didn't have a time then query 2 would find them.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of Comparing a DATE with another DATE...

Compare DateAsString with DateAsString...

**SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TO_CHAR(process_dt, 'mm/dd/yyyy') = '11/16/2013';**

BELOW QUERY RETURNS 0 ROWS: **am converting sysdate > string > date and compare!!**
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') from dual 
where 
SYSDATE = TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD')

Comment: Not a good idea. Stay with dates, as this prevents indexes being used, and doesn't work for anything other than equality conditions.

Comment: well, none of this has worked. idk why. the process up in the chain that is exchaning the partitions.. that might be causing this issue. I will dig into the code.